# Load image from disk in kotlin multiplatform

Tags: image, bitmap, kotlin-multiplatform

I have simple kotlin multiplatform project. And I want to display some PNG from my disk. How can I do that? For example, my image is located in `"D:\sample_image.png"`. I do not want to use resources at all.

Using `painter = painterResource("D:\sample_image.png")` does not work as this is not the resource.

`FileResourceLoader` is not available since it's Compose Desktop thingy.

Please note that I'm using `Kotlin Multiplatform`, and I need universal solution.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I resolved it... kinda.

**CommonMain**:

```
expect fun createBitmapFromFile(filepath: String): ImageBitmap?
```

**jvmMain**:

```
actual fun createBitmapFromFile(filepath: String): ImageBitmap? {
    val file = File(filepath)
    return if (file.exists()) {
        val inputStream = file.inputStream()
        return loadImageBitmap(inputStream)
    } else {
        null
    }
}
```

**iosMain**: **AI generated**, and I don't have option to test it. If anyone is kind enough to try it out and confirm it works, I would really appreciate it.

```
actual fun createBitmapFromFile(filePath: String): ImageBitmap? {
    val fileURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(filePath)
    val imageData = NSData.dataWithContentsOfURL(fileURL)
    val uiImage = UIImage.imageWithData(imageData)

    return if (uiImage != null) {
        return uiImage.toBitmap()
    } else {
        null
    }
}

private fun UIImage.toBitmap(): ImageBitmap {
    val cgImage = this.CGImage
    val data = cgImage.dataProvider?.data
    val bytes = data?.readBytes()?.toUByteArray()
    return Image.makeFromEncoded(bytes).asImageBitmap()
}
```